# Eclipse API Read all submodules/child modules

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I am trying to read all submodules of project. Below is the code which I wrote it is working as expected but I am not sure if this is an efficient way of reading all submodules of project. Please advice.

```
public static List<IResource> getMembers(IProject project){
List<IResource> childFolders = new ArrayList<IResource>();
try {
    IResource[] children = project.members();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
// not sure about this if condition part
        if (children[i].FOLDER == IResource.FOLDER && !children[i].toString().startsWith("L/")
                && !children[i].toString().contains(".")) {
            childFolders.add(children[i]);
            System.out.println(children[i]);
        }
    }
} catch (CoreException e) {
    LOGGER.debug(e.getMessage());
}
return childFolders;
}
```

Comment: Note: Jface is only the org.eclipse.jface code, and SWT is only org.eclipse.swt. What you have shown is all Eclipse APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children[i].FOLDER == IResource.FOLDER` doesn't do anything - `FOLDER` is a constant so it is always true.

You should never have to use `toString` to work out member types.

If you want a list of folders in a project you would use something like:

```
final List<IFolder> folders = new ArrayList<>();

for (final IResource resource : project.members()) {
  if (resource instanceof IFolder && !resource.getName().startsWith("."))
    folders.add((IFolder)resource);
}
```

or even:

```
List<IFolder> folders = Arrays.stream(project.members())
    .filter(resource -> !resource.getName().startsWith("."))
    .filter(IFolder.class::isInstance)
    .map(IFolder.class::cast)
    .toList();
```